# SQL complicated join

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to join the following 2 tables with the result below
this data is basically 2 tables that are joined on multi keys from both tables over some sort of group but i am drawing a blank as to how to accomplish this
I am using an Oracle database.

thanks

```html
<table border="0">
<tr><td><b>Table 1</b></td><td></td><td><b>Table 2</b></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Key</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

    </td>
    <td>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
            <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Users</th>
    <th>Key</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U3</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U4</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U4</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U4</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U5</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U5</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U5</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>RESULT</b></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
          <tr>
    <th>Users</th>
    <th>Groups</th>
  </tr>
        <tr><td>U1</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>U2</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><td>U3</td><td>A</td></tr>
        <tr><td>U4</td><td>A, B, C, D</td></tr>
        <tr><td>U5</td><td>A, D</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look at the LISTAGG() function.

Comment: I'm a little familiar with listagg however how do i perform the join between the 2 tables?   for example i can do a listagg on table of with the result of A 1, 2 : B 1,3 : C 1,2,3 : D 2, 4  but i need to join table 1 and 2 and THEN do a listagg (im having issues with the join of the 2 tables)

Comment: Please do not use the "code snippet" feature to post sample data. Just use plain text and format it as code through the `{}` button or just use `<pre>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
with grps as (select 'A' grp, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'A' grp, 2 key from dual union all
              select 'B' grp, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'B' grp, 3 key from dual union all
              select 'C' grp, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'C' grp, 2 key from dual union all
              select 'C' grp, 3 key from dual union all
              select 'D' grp, 2 key from dual union all
              select 'D' grp, 4 key from dual),
     usrs as (select 'U1' usr, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'U2' usr, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'U2' usr, 3 key from dual union all
              select 'U3' usr, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'U3' usr, 2 key from dual union all
              select 'U4' usr, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'U4' usr, 2 key from dual union all
              select 'U4' usr, 3 key from dual union all
              select 'U4' usr, 4 key from dual union all
              select 'U5' usr, 1 key from dual union all
              select 'U5' usr, 2 key from dual union all
              select 'U5' usr, 4 key from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables; see SQL below
select usr,
       listagg(case when usr_grp_cnt = grp_cnt then grp end, ', ') within group (order by grp) grps
from   (select u.usr,
               g.grp,
               g.grp_cnt,
               count(g.key) usr_grp_cnt
        from   usrs u
               left outer join (select grp,
                                       key,
                                       count(*) over (partition by grp) grp_cnt
                                from   grps) g on (g.key = u.key)
        group by u.usr,
                 g.grp,
                 g.grp_cnt)
group by usr;

USR GRPS           
--- ---------------
U1                 
U2  B              
U3  A              
U4  A, B, C, D     
U5  A, D
```

This works by first finding the number of keys per group (assuming that is unique), then it does an outer join to the usrs "table" (here, it's a subquery defined in the `WITH` clause; google subquery factoring if you're not familiar with it. You presumably have a table that's the equivalent of this subquery, so you'd just use that in the main sql statement).

Next, we find the count of the keys per user per group, and then we can use that to work out which groups match, by checking that the user+group key count is the same as the group key count. Then we use the listagg function to aggregate that into a list.

N.B. I had to change the data for user U3, since originally, your data had the same keys as for user U5.